# Apache proxypass issue with firefox

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, vhosts, proxypass

I've got a wordpress blog running in a docker container, and I'm trying to reverse proxy to it from a virtualhost in the host's apache config. My vhost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  my.vhost.com
    ProxyRequests     off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8084/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8084/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit it in chrome, it works fine. When I pull it through curl it looks fine. But when I go to the my.vhost.com in firefox it redirects me to the host ip address (no port).

Does anyone know what's going on here?